# Are JAR files machine dependent

Tags: java, jar

I am making a math reflexes game in Java using the Eclipse Juno IDE. From the research I have already done, the IDE compiles everything into `.class` files *bytecode* upon save! The problem now is that I have tried extracting everything to JAR *from a Windows machine*, and giving the JAR to some beta-testers. The beta-testers reported problems upon trying to access it from a Linux/Mac. I also know already that a runnable JAR *what I was extracting everything to* is basically a glorified ZIP *compressed file* containing the bytecode that the JVM understands and executes. Given that my game has multiple `.java` files, I would like to know if:

1. the packaging of the bytecode into a JAR is machine-dependent
2. my options to ensure that ALL USERS are able to play my game //and reap the benefits; it is also worth pointing out that my computer does not have javac.exe; that program is reported outdated by Sun Microsystems

   ```
   System.out.println("Thanks for your patience in advance!");
   ```

Comment: On of the most important java advantages is bytecode portability. You still have a question?

Comment: Yes, JAR files and their contents are fully platform independent.  You need to explain what problems you are having on Windows machines - perhaps the users are not invoking Java properly?

Comment: *"beta-testers reported problems upon trying to access it from a Linux/Mac"* What problems?

Comment: it just won't open //I am sending them the .jar file...

Answer (score 5):

1. Java bytecode is fully platform-independent
2. Everybody who has rights to run JVM can play your game

From official [platform-overview](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/index.html):

> The Java virtual machine is an abstract computing machine that has an instruction set and manipulates memory at run time. The Java virtual machine is ported to different platforms to provide hardware- and operating system-independence.

Answer (score 0):

Found out that Mac computers are only running Java 6 //and I might be using code exclusive to Java 7

Comment: Never mind; the problem resides elsewhere. It deals with object serialization. More about it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15607969/appending-objects-to-a-serialization-file