# Appending Objects to a serialization file

Tags: java, object, serialization

Suppose you have some AppendObjectOutputStream class (which is an ObjectOutputStream!) which overrides writeStreamHeader() like this:

```
@Override
public void writeStreamHeader() throws IOException
{
    reset();
}
```

Now also, let's say you plan on saving multiple objects to a file; one object for each time your program runs. Would you, even on the first run, use AppendObjectOutputStream()?

Comment: You don't want to do this. You will run into subtle semantic bugs with reference sharing depending on exactly where a new sub-stream starts.

Comment: So, what is being suggested (and the route I ended up taking) is to writeStreamHeader() the first time by using a plain ObjectOutputStream, and then append records with AppendObjectOutputStream as defined above?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to write the stream header first time with regular ObjectOutputStream otherwise you will get java.io.StreamCorruptedException on opening the file with ObjectInputStream.

```
public class Test1 implements Serializable {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ObjectOutputStream os1 = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("test"));
        os1.writeObject(new Test1());
        os1.close();

        ObjectOutputStream os2 = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("test", true)) {
            protected void writeStreamHeader() throws IOException {
                reset();
            }
        };

        os2.writeObject(new Test1());
        os2.close();

        ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("test"));
        System.out.println(is.readObject());
        System.out.println(is.readObject());
```

Comment: This is exactly what I am doing the first time; writing the file header first time with regular ObjectOutputStream, and then, on all other sessions of this program, using AppendObjectOutputStream, but I still get StreamCorruptedException! //In fact, I get this running my program FOR THE VERY FIRST TIME: invalid stream header: 79737200 . The topmost entry from my code on the callstack comes from the records = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("record.ser")); statement

Comment: try my test, it definitely works, i suspect you do not close the outputstream

Comment: The OutputStream is being closed; I wish I could send you the Java files, but I am working on a math game that I actually intend on having people play, and I don't want people taking advantage of my code floating around.

Answer (score 0):

The above did not work for me, specifically the reset() did not work.
I found the following here:
https://coderanch.com/t/583191/java/ObjectOutputStream-appending-file-overiding-ObjectOutputStream

```
@Override 
protected void writeStreamHeader() throws IOException {  
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
   System.out.println("I am called");  
   super.writeStreamHeader();
}
```

This worked for me.  I know it seems counter-intuitive and at first blush it seems like calling the superclass method should not do anything, but it does.  Read the original post and try it.