# How to add data to the serialized file in java?

Tags: java, serialization

I want to serialize list of `ArrayList` type to the file. But the size of this list could be changed from time to time, for example if its size was 10000 elements, then after some time I may add another 10000 elements.
I am using the following code for serialization:

```
public class Serializer {

    private Serializer() {
    }

    public static void serialize(String filename, List<String> list) {

        try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(filename);
             ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fos)) {
            out.writeObject(list);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static List<String> deserialize(String filename) {
        try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filename);
             ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fis)) {
            return (List<String>) in.readObject();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return new ArrayList<>();
    }
}
```

I want to know if there is a way to serialize data on top of an existing file without overwriting it from scratch.

Comment: The answer is no. Your should really, really fix your exception handling. Ignoring exceptions as if nothing happened is really not a good idea.

Comment: I will have to rewrite the file, right?

Comment: Yes, since you asked if there was a way to do it without overwriting it, and I answered no.

Comment: The dupe is not a dupe. The question is not to append an object to a serialized stream. It's to add an element to a single list serialized in a file.

Comment: @MichałZaborowski In your example it is adding new object each time, but in my case I am serializing the same Object, i.e. ArrayList but with modification.

Comment: @MichałZaborowski But this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15607969/appending-objects-to-a-serialization-file is also useful, because I can also write multiple objects and add them to the ArrayList after reading.

Comment: @JClean That is what I've understood. Once you have list of strings, and you serialize it. Then that list is changing, and you serialize it again. Each of the object can have any size, and you can't just start writting any place. If that is what you want to do - please use SQLite. There are pages, and you can change any object in the list.

Comment: @MichałZaborowski You are right regarding SQLite. This is really good solution. I will use it. Thanks