# Class cast Exception reading a written file of an ArrayList of Show Objects

Tags: java

```
/**
     * A method that writes variables in a file for shows in the program.
     * 
     * @author 
     * @version (1.2 2022.01.05)
     */
    public void writeShowData(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException{
        String showPath = "c:\\Users\\COMPUTER\\bluej files\\projects\\chapter15\\willem\\CinemaReservationSystemFiles\\";
        try
        {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(showPath+fileName,true);
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
            oos.writeObject(show);
            oos.flush();
            oos.close();
        }catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    
    /**
     * A method that reads variables in a file for shows setup use in the program.
     * 
     * @author 
     * @version (1.2 2022.01.05)
     */
    public void readShowData(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException {          
        try
        {   FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fileName);
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
            List <Show>shows =(List<Show>)ois.readObject();
            ois.close();
            System.out.println(shows.toString());// for testing    
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

the line : `List <Show> shows= (List<Show>)ois.readObject();` gives a

> ClassCastexception :class Show cannot be cast to class java.util.List
> (etc etc....

I tried many things but can't get it working well.

I made the class show and related classes
`Serializable` and then write it to shows.ser but when it reads it goes wrong.

Who can help me out on this?

Comment: Probably the file content can not be cast to Show class. You may take a look at it.

Comment: code is writing one instance of `Show` and trying to read a `List`.

Comment: @ Reza Khahani ShowClass exists out of : string showName,string showDate, SeatPlan seatPlan, Theatre theatre, int showNumber, int seatplanNumber, int theatreNumber. List <Show>shows is the ArrayList from where the file was written.

Comment: @user16320675 that is correct writes on at a time  and the read is when i start up the code again to fill the ArrayList <Show> shows

Comment: sure not, `(List<Show>)ois.readObject();` is NOT filling an list, it is reading an instance of `Show` and **trying** to cast it to a list, which does not work, since `Show` is not a `List` (or a subclass of `List`) - `readObject()` reads ONE object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is my latest version that is working, the new code does leave out a few lines like if(file.exists){file.delete()}.etc... because the used streams doing that automaticly.
i totally overwrite the file(s) with an update method instead of writing one object at a time.
The earlier answers and some testing by myself made me understand how to get it done right for the purposes in my code.

```
/**
     * A method that writes/saves variables of an Arraylist in a file for seatReservations in the program.
     * 
     * @author Willem
     * @version (1.6 2022.01.20)
     */
    public void overWriteShowData(String fileName1) throws FileNotFoundException {
        String seatReservationPath = "c:\\Users\\COMPUTER\\bluej files\\projects\\chapter15\\willem\\CinemaReservationSystemFiles\\";
        try
        { File file = new File(seatReservationPath + fileName1);
            ObjectOutputStream oos;
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file.getCanonicalPath(),false); // regular fos
            oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
            oos.writeObject(shows);
            oos.flush();
            oos.close();
        }catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }    

/**
     * A method that reads variables in a file for shows setup use in the program.
     * 
     * @author 
     * @version (1.6 2022.01.20)
     */
    public void readShowData(String fileName1) throws IOException, EOFException,ClassNotFoundException{                       
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fileName1);
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
        shows = (List<Show>) ois.readObject();
        ois.close();
    }

private void updateAllData(String fileName) {
      try {
        if(fileName.equals("theatres.ser"))
        {overWriteTheatreData(fileName);}
        if(fileName.equals("seatPlans.ser"))
        {overWriteSeatPlanData(fileName);}
        if(fileName.equals("shows.ser"))
        {overWriteShowData(fileName);}
        if(fileName.equals("customers.ser"))
        {overWriteCustomerData(fileName);}
        if(fileName.equals("seatReservations.ser"))
        {overWriteSeatReservationData(fileName);}
      } catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
            //fnfe.printStackTrace();
             CinemaReservationSystemGUI.cannotFindFileMessage(fileName);
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved your problem as below. Firstly, you need to change your writing method. If a data file does not exist, you need to create a regular (without append) `FileOuputStream` for stream header otherwise you will get `java.io.StreamCorruptedException` ([ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15608076/14868118)). `FileOutputStream` should be created differently for the next additions.

```java
public static void writeShowData(String fileName) {
        String showPath = "E:\\path\\";
        try {
            File file = new File(showPath + fileName);
            ObjectOutputStream oos;
            if(file.exists()) {
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file.getAbsolutePath(), true); // with reset fos
                oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos) {
                    protected void writeStreamHeader() throws IOException {
                        reset();
                    }
                };
            } else {
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file.getAbsolutePath()); // regular fos
                oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
            }
            
            oos.writeObject(show);
            oos.flush();
            oos.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Secondly, you need to modify your reading method. If your `FileInputStream` has data, you need to iterate to add your list.

```java
public static void readShowData(String fileName) {
        try {
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("E:\\path\\" + fileName);
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);

            List<Show> shows = new ArrayList<>();
            while (fis.available() > 0) {
                Show s = (Show) ois.readObject();
                System.out.println(s.number);
                shows.add(s);
            }

            ois.close();
        } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much this code does the job. I appreciate your help.

Comment: You're welcome @Willem .  Please click the green outlined checkmark if the solution helped you.

Comment: well sergey Afinogenov what do you suggest then?  in addition to this code.

Comment: It is not recommended to use available method because this returns number of blocks can be read without blocking the next caller, in other words it can return 0 even if there are more bytes to read. Use EOFException handling instead @oktaykcr

Comment: I will use EOFException handling and change the code accordingly!